# P-value of features when using Random Forests

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest, feature-selection, p-value

I am using Random forests in scikit-learn and I'm wondering is there any way I can get p-value of features?
I know I can use feature_importances_ to get the importance of features, but I need to have the p-value. Also similar to coefficients (using linear regression) I need to know how features are contributing to prediction, how the predicted value changes with changes in each features.

Comment: what you're looking for is Z-scores. Not sure if implemented in scikit. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/17501/how-do-you-calculate-variable-importance-p-values-using-the-randomforest-package

Comment: and to investigate your mapping curvature, you can try partial dependence plots or closely related sensitivity analysis or.... a shameless advice:) jump to R and try my package forestFloor to visualize random forests. We have z-score also :http://www.statistik.uni-dortmund.de/useR-2008/slides/Strobl+Zeileis.pdf

Comment: As far as I know Z-score does not give any intuition about how the value of feature is affecting the class. For e.g. if value of feature 1 is greater it belongs to class X with higher probability. How can I get this one?

Comment: @"is there any way I can get p-value of features?" Z-scores is roughly analogues to linear regression post-test t-scores. Read instructions carefully...

Comment: @"I need to know how features are contributing to prediction."  That was my second answer.... and to investigate your mapping curvature...

Comment: Unlike linear regression models which are explicitly stated in simple equation,s RF model fits often have incomprehensible long explicitly stated equations/tree-maps. In stead you look at how the function maps from feature space to target space. http://repositorium.sdum.uminho.pt/bitstream/1822/14836/1/blackbox.pdf